# Spring Security, complex object as authority

Tags: spring-security

does anyone know how to use a complex object as a spring security authority, and not to implement custom accessDecisionManager. I don't want to implement a custom accessDecisionManager because I then need to reimplement role voter too, that works with SPeL and think that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, probably the easiest is to wire a bean:

```
@Component
public class MyAuthorizer {
    boolean authorize(Authentication authentication) {
        // do your custom checking here
    }
}
```

And then

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @PreAuthorize("@myAuthorizer.authorize(authentication)")
    // ... request mapping, etc
}
```

Or, if it is possible to reduce your complex object down to a string,  `hasAuthority` will work just as it does with simple authorities:

```
public class MyCustomAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
    Object all;
    Object my;
    Object complexity;

    public String getAuthority() {
        return String.valueOf(this.complexity);
    }
}
```